# В чем проблема распределенного тестирования jmeter?

Tags: java, jmeter

При запуске ui на slave сервере нагрузка подается правильно, постепенно, 10 потоков, 10 рпс, при remote запуске удаленного джметра с мастер сервера нагрузка практически вовсе не подается, бывает, что проскочит 20 рпс в секунду, и 10 секунд пусто. То есть само соединение с удаленной тачкой есть, нагрузка подается, но не так, как через ручной пуск на slave сервере, а криво. Что можно сделать в такой ситуации? Ключ настроен. На slave сервере jmeter-server запущен. Remote хост прописан в проперти. Версия джавы идентична, сервера в одной сети.

Единственная зацепка в том, что джметр лог выдает этот стектрейс:

````
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
  at org.apache.jmeter.threads.UnmodifiableJMeterVariables.put(UnmodifiableJMeterVariables.java:71) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
  at org.apache.jmeter.functions.Property.execute(Property.java:80) ~[ApacheJMeter_functions.jar:5.4.1]
  at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:138) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
  at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:113) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
  at org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FunctionProperty.getStringValue(FunctionProperty.java:91) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
  at org.apache.jmeter.testelement.AbstractTestElement.getPropertyAsString(AbstractTestElement.java:280) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
  at org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector.getFilename(ResultCollector.java:192) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
  at org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector.testStarted(ResultCollector.java:324) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
  at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.RemoteSampleListenerImpl.testStarted(RemoteSampleListenerImpl.java:73) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
  at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
  at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
  at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
  at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
  at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
  at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
  at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
  at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_351]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_351]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_351]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_351]```
````

Comment: Обращайтесь в службу поддержки jmeter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем вопросе слишком мало информации, мы не можем определить причину, скорее всего где-то ошибка конфигурации

1. Используйте [последнюю стабильную версию JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) (на данный момент это [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5))
2. Проверьте что мастер машина имеет доступ до генератора(ов) нагрузки и наоборот. Все [RMI порты](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote) должны быть открыты в firewall
3. Выставьте [уровень логгирования](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) в DEBUG на мастере и генераторах нагрузки и проверьте файлы `jmeter.log` и `jmeter-server.log` на предмет "подозрительных" записей
4. Попробуйте запустить тест в master-slave режиме на одной машине, то есть запускаете скрипт `jmeter-server` и на ней же `jmeter -R 127.0.0.1 -n -t ..\extras\Test.jmx -f -l result.jtl`